# How do I display a final score and high score on gameover screen?

Tags: android, libgdx, preferences, points

I am using libgdx and I am trying to figure out how to display the final score my players achieve, and the overall high score for their games when the game goes to the game over screen. I am unsure as to how to bring the score integer over from the game screen to the game over screen.

Comment: you can use  preferences to store the last high score and  current score and get into the game over screen and show it ..

Comment: I figured I might be able to use preferences, but I don't know how to initialize and use them. I tried looking at the documentation for preferences but I didn't quite understand it.

Comment: https://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1585 try this and if you don't understand from documentation try to get any example it's make essay to understand

Comment: @Amitpandey is right, usually you want to store game score into preferences. Preferences are file based, so everything you need to save like scores can go in.
Another way is to use your own file save system but hey, preferences is already made so, you should go ahead and use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1: Storing high score using preferences

I think you want to be able to close the game (close the window or kill the app) and have the high scores stored for the next time someone plays the game (executes the game or opens the app).

In this case preferences are the way to go and here's a simple example:

**Game class**

```java
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Preferences;

public class PreferenceExample extends Game {

    @Override
    public void create() {
        // Initialize the preferences
        Preferences preferences = Gdx.app.getPreferences("examplePreferences");
        // Go to your game screen sending this LibGDX Game and the LibGDX Preferences
        setScreen(new GameScreen(this, preferences));
    }
}
```

**Game screen class**

```java
import com.badlogic.gdx.Preferences;
import com.badlogic.gdx.ScreenAdapter;

class GameScreen extends ScreenAdapter {

    private PreferenceExample game;
    private Preferences preferences;

    GameScreen(PreferenceExample game, Preferences preferences) {
        // Store reference to LibGDX Game
        this.game = game;
        // Store reference to LibGDX Preferences
        this.preferences = preferences;
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.L)) {
            saveHighScore(MathUtils.random(3));
            goToGameOverScreen();
        }
    }

    // Call this whenever you want to save the high score
    private void saveHighScore(int highScore) {
        preferences.putInteger("High score", highScore);
        preferences.flush();
    }

    // Call this whenever you want to switch to the game over screen
    private void goToGameOverScreen() {
        game.setScreen(new GameOverScreen(preferences));
    }
}
```

**Game over screen class**

```java
import com.badlogic.gdx.Preferences;
import com.badlogic.gdx.ScreenAdapter;

class GameOverScreen extends ScreenAdapter {

    private Preferences preferences;
    private int highScore;

    GameOverScreen(Preferences preferences) {
        // Store reference to LibGDX Preferences
        this.preferences = preferences;
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        // Load high score, default value is 0 in case you didn't store it properly
        highScore = preferences.getInteger("High score", 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        // Do something with the high score you retrieved
        System.out.println(highScore);
    }
}
```

**Warning**: be aware that storing and retrieving methods from `Preferences` are case sensitive so it is a good idea to put the `String` referencing the value on a variable to minimize mistakes.

### Option 2: Passing high score between screens

Maybe you don't need the high scores stored for when the game is closed so passing the high score information from one screen to another should be easier, here's an example:

**Game class**

```java
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;

public class ScreenToScreenExample extends Game {

    @Override
    public void create() {
        // Go to your game screen sending this LibGDX Game and the LibGDX Preferences
        setScreen(new GameScreen(this));
    }
}
```

**Game screen class**

```java
import com.badlogic.gdx.ScreenAdapter;

class GameScreen extends ScreenAdapter {

    private ScreenToScreenExample game;
    private int highScore;

    GameScreen(ScreenToScreenExample game) {
        // Store reference to LibGDX Game
        this.game = game;
    }

    // Call this whenever you want to save the high score
    void saveHighScore(int highScore) {
        this.highScore = highScore;
    }

    // Call this whenever you want to switch to the game over screen
    void goToGameOverScreen() {
        game.setScreen(new GameOverScreen(highScore));
    }
}
```

**Game over screen class**

```java
import com.badlogic.gdx.ScreenAdapter;

class GameOverScreen extends ScreenAdapter {

    private int highScore;

    GameOverScreen(int highScore) {
        this.highScore = highScore;
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        // Do something with the high score you retrieved
        System.out.println(highScore);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll have to use both methods because I need to pass the current score from the play screen to the game over screen. As well as store and update the current high score. I'll update when I've made an attempt on this, I'm at work currently.

Comment: Try Option 1 when you can, I think it does what you need, it passes the high score to the game over screen and also updates and stores it

Comment: I am trying to get option 1 working, however, I keep getting a NullPointerException when moving from the game screen to the game over screen.

Comment: Try having the barebones for it to work, I just copy pasted my code into Android Studio and tested sending a random int between 1 and 3 it works just fine

Comment: I figured out where I went wrong. I didn't initialize preferences in my game class. I now have it printing 0 to the system

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the best way, but you can keep the score in the main class that extends `Game`.

```java
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;

public class MyGame extends Game {
    private int score;

    // Add getters and setters
}
```

Then in your screen classes you can do:

```java
MyGame myGame = (MyGame) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener();
// Then you can set
myGame.setScore(score);
// or get the score
int score = myGame.getScore();
```

If you have multiple values to store, you can create a class and keep an instance of it in your `MyGame` class. You will put the `score` and other properties in this class.

You can also create a static method in `MyGame` class that do the cast for you:

```java
public static MyGame get() {
    return (MyGame) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener();
}
```

Then you can do `MyGame.get().setScore(score);`
or: `int score = MyGame.get().getScore();`